# minority carrier life time? Why is it important for devices' switching speed. Why not majority carriers?

Tags: semiconductor-physics

I am trying to get my head around why would and silicon engineer care about the minority life time carrier and how does the minority carrier affect the switching speed of PN junction. Why is it so much about minority and not majority carriers?

Comment: why this question is closed even though it points to the specific subject matter (and already had an accepted answer)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The intutitive answer is that [minority carriers lifetime](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minority_carrier_lifetime) delineate the analysis because they are minority.

This may sound a tautology but consider this simple game which goes on as long as it holds:

There are $n$ *monkeys* and $m$ ($m < n$) *donkeys*. The game involves monkeys taking pairs with donkeys and unpairing. The game goes on as long as at least one monkey and one donkey are free.

Since both entities are necessary for the game but one entity may (due to population) run short earlier, which population lifetime bounds the whole game lifetime?

Comment: That really make sense now, Nikos!. So pairing and non- paring refers to the generation and recombination of electron-hole (monkey-donkey) pairs right? When majority recombines with all the minority carriers and no minority carrier is left, the material changes its state and the On/off switching takes the effect. right?

Comment: @dr3patel, yes exactly, the "game" needs both, so the rest follows :)